# Toggle ScheduledExecutorService so its not always running

Tags: java, discord-jda

I'm currently working on a discord bot just to mess around with, but have used SES in the past for other things, but I always struggle to disable/enable the SES, calling `ses.shutdown();` does not work and the runnable continues, and if I did shutdown im not sure how to restart it.

Here is my current code...

```
private final ScheduledExecutorService ses = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

protected void startRainbow(Role rle) {
    roleRainbow[] colors = roleRainbow.values();
    HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("loop", 0);

    Runnable r = () -> {

        if(map.get("loop") >= colors.length) {
            map.put("loop", 0);
        }



        rle.getManager().setColor(Color.decode(colors[map.get("loop")].toString())).queue();
        System.out.println("color is: " + colors[map.get("loop")].toString());
        System.out.println("color from role: " + rle.getColor());

        map.put("loop", map.get("loop") + 1);
    };

    ses.scheduleAtFixedRate(r, 1L, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two angles to this problem:

- Interrupting a currently-running thread.
- Graceful shut down of a scheduled executor service.

The first has been addressed [many many times on Stack Overflow](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com%20java%20interrupt%20thread&t=osx&ia=web) already. In brief: You must signal a thread that you want it to interrupt itself. That thread's task must be coded is such a way to look for the interruption signal.

For the second, there are two steps involved:

- You first tell the scheduled executor service that you want to stop any further executions of future-scheduled tasks. We do this with a call to [`shutdown`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown()). This call does *not* interrupt any currently existing task (see above paragraph).

  - Alternatively, you may call [`shutdownNow`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdownNow()). This call *may* signal the running task to interrupt, but no guarantees. The behavior is implementation-defined.
- After requesting the service to stop further scheduling, you can watch to see if the service does indeed stop after a reasonable amount of time has passed. We do this with a call to [`awaitTermination`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination(long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)).

```java
ScheduledExecutorService ses = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor() ;
ses.scheduleAtFixedRate( task , initialDelay , period , timeUnit ) ;
…
ses.shutdown() ;
boolean terminated = false ;
try { terminated  = ses.awaitTermination( 1 , TimeUnit.MINUTES ); } catch ( InterruptedException e ) { e.printStackTrace(); }
if( ! terminated ) { … Houston, we have a problem. … }
```

The call to `shutdown` (and `shutdownNow`) does *not* block; it does not wait for anything to happen, and does not wait for tasks to end.

The call to `awaitTermination` *does* block until either:

- Scheduled executor service finishes its last running task, and ends.
- The specified time-out elapses.

Test for the boolean returned by the `awaitTermination` call. To quote the Javadoc:

> `true` if this executor terminated and `false` if the timeout elapsed before termination

You asked:

> if I did shutdown im not sure how to restart it.

Once shutdown, the scheduled executor service is done. To schedule tasks for execution, you must instantiate a new scheduled executor service.

Be aware that a scheduled executor service with no tasks to execute takes **very little memory or CPU**. So no need to shutdown if you might later need the service.

However, be sure to *always* shutdown your executor services before your app ends. Otherwise the backing thread pool(s) may continue running indefinitely, like a zombie ‍♂️.